# Change type of control based on type of item source?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm

I am working with MVVM design pattern where I want to change the type of control to be used based on the type of item source object.
My code for item source types :

```
public class PropertyItemVM : ViewModelBase
{
   // Some base code for all basic  property items
}

public class StringValuePropertyItemVM : PropertyItemVM
{
   // Code to correctly create string value property item
}

public class ComboBoxPropertyItemVM : PropertyItemVM
{
   // Code to correctly create combo box property item
}
```

In my view model I have property list binded to xaml as

```
public ObservableCollection<PropertyItemVM> Properties { get; set; }
```

This collection contains both the types of objects `StringValuePropertyItemVM` and `ComboBoxPropertyItemVM`.

Now what I want to achieve is, based on type of object I want to decide whether the xaml will contain a `TextBox` or a `ComboBox`.

My xaml code :

```
<StackPanel>
    <!--Items Control containing all list of properties to be shown-->
    <ItemsControl x:Name="Local" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" Background="White">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="{Binding Label}" 
                           IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <!-- Here based on type need to change the TextBox with ComboBox-->
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             Grid.Column="1"
                             IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

With some help I found out I can have different data templates for both types and switch among those, however I can't find how to do that. Can anyone help me with how can this be achieved ?

Comment: It seems, that you'll need own [`DataTemplateSelector `](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Automatic Data Template Selection

Move the data templates to the `ItemsControl` resources and assign a `DataType`.

```
<StackPanel>
   <!--Items Control containing all list of properties to be shown-->
   <ItemsControl x:Name="Local" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" Background="White">
      <ItemsControl.Resources>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:StringValuePropertyItemVM}">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

               <Label Content="{Binding Label}" 
                      IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
                      Grid.Column="0"/>
               <!-- Here based on type need to change the TextBox with ComboBox-->
               <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxPropertyItemVM}">
            <ComboBox/>
         </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.Resources>
   </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The `ItemsControl` will automatically select the right data template based on the type.

### Data Template Selector

Although you do not need it in this case, for more complex cases (e.g. conditions based on the view model), you could implement a `DataTemplateSelector`, like this:

```
public class PropertyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
   public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
   {
      if (!(container is FrameworkElement frameworkElement))
         return null;

      switch (item)
      {
         case StringValuePropertyItemVM _:
            return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource("StringValuePropertyItemVMDataTemplate");
         case ComboBoxPropertyItemVM _:
            return (DataTemplate)frameworkElement.FindResource("ComboBoxPropertyItemVMDataTemplate");
         default:
            return null;
      }
   }
}
```

Then you would define the data templates in a resource dictionary in scope with keys.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="StringValuePropertyItemVMDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:StringValuePropertyItemVM}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <Label Content="{Binding Label}" 
             IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"
             Grid.Column="0"/>
      <!-- Here based on type need to change the TextBox with ComboBox-->
      <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
               Grid.Column="1"
               IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxPropertyItemVMDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxPropertyItemVM}">
   <ComboBox/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Finally, you would assign or reference an instance of the selector to the `ItemsControl`.

```
<StackPanel>
   <!--Items Control containing all list of properties to be shown-->
   <ItemsControl x:Name="Local" ItemsSource="{Binding Properties}" Background="White">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
         <local:PropertyDataTemplateSelector/>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
   </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```